# How to place footnotes using longtable package with letter marks instead of numbers?

Tags: footnotes, longtable

I have the table below as MWE. I couldn't get the footnotes with letter marks. When I use `\footnote` and `\footnotetext` macros they default to using number marks, I want to use letters like `a`, `b`, etc. instead.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{r r r r r r}
\caption{Here is the caption} \\
\toprule
Time & MAD\footnote{a} & Group\footnote{b} & Par1 & Par2 & Par3 \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
\footnotetext{Median Absolute Deviation}
\footnotetext{Second footnote}
0     & 10.839 & 0     & 111.5 & 109.6 & 89.3  \\
200   & 10.854 & 0     & 111.6 & 109.6 & 89.3  \\
400   & 10.869 & 0     & 111.7 & 109.8 & 89.3  \\
600   & 10.898 & 0     & 111.8 & 109.9 & 89.3  \\
799   & 10.903 & 0     & 111.9 & 109.9 & 89.3  \\
0     & 10.916 & 0     & 112.1 & 110.1 & 89.5  \\
200   & 10.901 & 0     & 112.2 & 110.2 & 89.5  \\
400   & 10.569 & 0     & 112.4 & 110.4 & 89.5  \\
600   & 7.6   & 0     & 112.4 & 110.4 & 89.7  \\
799   & 4.861 & 0     & 112.5 & 110.4 & 90.6  \\
0     & 2.984 & 0     & 112.4 & 110.5 & 91.3  \\
200   & 0.74  & 0     & 112.3 & 110.3 & 91.1  \\
400   & 0.378 & 0     & 111.5 & 109.6 & 90.7  \\
600   & 0.391 & 0     & 111.7 & 109.6 & 90.9  \\
799   & 0.344 & 0     & 111.6 & 109.9 & 91.1  \\
0     & 0.388 & 0     & 111.9 & 110   & 91.6  \\
200   & 0.381 & 0     & 112.5 & 110.2 & 92    \\
400   & 0.366 & 0     & 112.6 & 110.4 & 92.6  \\
600   & 0.336 & 0     & 112.9 & 110.7 & 93    \\
799   & 0.328 & 0     & 113.1 & 110.9 & 93.6  \\
0     & 0.329 & 0     & 113.2 & 111.2 & 94.1  \\
200   & 0.393 & 0     & 113.4 & 111.4 & 95    \\
400   & 0.362 & 0     & 113.6 & 111.6 & 95.6  \\
600   & 0.345 & 0     & 113.8 & 111.9 & 96.3  \\
799   & 0.343 & 0     & 113.9 & 112.1 & 80    \\
0     & 0.335 & 0     & 113.9 & 112.4 & 97.6  \\
200   & 0.374 & 0     & 113.2 & 112.6 & 98.3  \\
400   & 0.403 & 0     & 114.6 & 112.9 & 98.9  \\
600   & 0.381 & 0     & 114.4 & 113.3 & 99.4  \\
799   & 0.388 & 0     & 115   & 113.7 & 100.1 \\
0     & 0.387 & 0     & 114.7 & 114.2 & 100.8 \\
200   & 0.41  & 0     & 115.3 & 115   & 101.9 \\
400   & 0.41  & 0     & 116.5 & 116.3 & 101.8 \\
600   & 0.421 & 0     & 117.5 & 118.6 & 102.3 \\
799   & 0.431 & 0     & 119.9 & 123.6 & 102.7 \\
0     & 0.442 & 0     & 125.3 & 132   & 103.3 \\
200   & 0.448 & 0     & 135.8 & 141.5 & 103.8 \\
400   & 0.465 & 0     & 151.1 & 147.4 & 104.4 \\
600   & 0.485 & 0     & 164.4 & 155.3 & 105.3 \\
799   & 0.495 & 0     & 181.1 & 175.6 & 106.4 \\
0     & 0.55  & 0     & 216.6 & 196.5 & 107.8 \\
200   & 0.561 & 0     & 246.8 & 215.1 & 108.1 \\
400   & 0.604 & 0     & 278   & 244   & 174.5 \\
600   & 0.646 & 0     & 304.2 & 273.1 & 174.1 \\
799   & 0.725 & 0     & 326.1 & 284.4 & 173.4 \\
0     & 0.759 & 0     & 337.3 & 293.5 & 172.5 \\
200   & 0.837 & 0     & 340.7 & 301.8 & 171.8 \\
400   & 0.864 & 0     & 342.3 & 306.3 & 170.6 \\
600   & 0.701 & 0     & 345.4 & 309.7 & 169.7 \\
799   & 0.876 & 0     & 346.2 & 307.6 & 169.1 \\
0     & 0.886 & 0     & 343.7 & 306.2 & 168.6 \\
200   & 0.876 & 0     & 340.9 & 305.4 & 168   \\
\label{tab:addlabel}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

In the same subject, I am intending to put all the footnotes on the first page, but considering readability of the table, is there any problem in doing that? or should I repeat all footnotes over the the pages spanned by the longtable? what should be expected from the side of the trained reader?

Comment: I'd simply add in the caption that “MAD” stands for “Mean Absolute Deviation” rather than using a footnote.

Comment: clear, but suppose that you have several footnotes, so I would end up with footnotes.

Comment: longtable just uses the standard footnote counter formatting so `\renewcommand\thefootnote{\alph{footnote}}` at some point before the table

Comment: +1, I will upvote also as an answer and from author himself! I have another question on the caption of longtable, can you pls have a look?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, if I have only one and the same footnote for 3 different long tables, they will go like a, b, c. while they should be a, a, a in the 3 tables, so how to reset the footnote counter in this case?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Care to make an answer, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`longtable` just uses the standard footnote counter formatting so

```
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\alph{footnote}}
```

at some point before the table

You ask in comments about resetting, it's a standard counter so

```
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
```

(or any other number)

or you can use the `\footnote[5]{xxx}` form to force the re-use of a number.